# Icon divs not showing up on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 icons on the landing page I'm building, each in their own div. For some reason, rather than keeping all 4 on the same line and resizing automatically, it keeps 3 on one line, and the 4th is always on a 2nd line, as you can see in the image below. What could be causing this to happen to just that one icon?

[image]

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="services-positioning">
                <div class="col-md-4 service-content sc1">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-hdd-o"></i></span>
                    <h4>Get Inspired</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 service-content sc2">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i></span>
                    <h4>Get Rewarded</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 service-content sc3">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
                    <h4>Be Creative</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 service-content sc4">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
                    <h4>Stay Connected</h4>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
#services {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#services2 .col-md-4 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.service-content {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*
#services-positioning{
    display: inline-block;
}
*/

.service-content span {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto 25px;
    color: #3498db;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table;
    font-size: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 22px;
}

.service-content:hover span {
    background: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}

.service-content:hover i {
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}

.service-content h4 {
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service-content p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.service-content a {
    color: #3498DB;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.service-content a i {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.service-content a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from col-md-4 to col-md-3. In Bootstrap, "col-md-4" means that, on a "medium"-width viewport (or larger), the element will span across 4 columns out of a total of 12 (twelve is just the arbitrary number of columns that exist in Bootstrap). Thus, only 3 items with that class name can fit in a line.

Here's [a nice visual explanation of Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) from their official docs.